# How do I change the URL used to access Craft?

Tags: admin

By default you can access Craft on a site by visiting `/admin`. How can I change the URL for this to something else?

For example: `/new-url`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [cpTrigger](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#cpTrigger) config setting is what you're looking for.

Comment: So simple! Thanks Brad, will mark this as the answer when I can.

Answer (score 7):

You can edit this in the general config https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#cpTrigger

```
return array(
    'cpTrigger' => new-url,
);
```